# Extracing CV results of feature subsets in mlr

Tags: r, ensemble-learning, mlr

The mlr package provides the opportunity to fuse a learner with a random feature subset. Uncorrelated subsets could be useful to make a voting ensemble/averaging ensemble. This might be interesting if the features are partly redundant due different feature engineering procedures or just because different subsets give uncorrelated (but similar) results.
In order to use this, I have to calculate the correlation between the CV results but I don´t know how to extract them.

Here is a small example as at the GitHub page:

```
ctrl = makeFeatSelControlRandom(maxit = 5L)

rdesc = makeResampleDesc("CV", iters = 10)

sfeats = selectFeatures(learner = "classif.randomForest", 
task = iris.task, 
resampling = rdesc,
control = ctrl)

print(sfeats)    

With control class: FeatSelControlRandom
Imputation value: 1
[FeatSel-x] 1: 0101 (2 bits)
[FeatSel-y] 1: mmce.test.mean=0.0733333; time: 0.0 min
[FeatSel-x] 1: 1001 (2 bits)
[FeatSel-y] 1: mmce.test.mean=0.0466667; time: 0.0 min
[FeatSel-x] 1: 1001 (2 bits)
[FeatSel-y] 1: mmce.test.mean=0.0466667; time: 0.0 min
[FeatSel-x] 1: 0000 (0 bits)
[FeatSel-y] 1: mmce.test.mean=0.6333333; time: 0.0 min
[FeatSel-x] 1: 0110 (2 bits)
[FeatSel-y] 1: mmce.test.mean=0.0533333; time: 0.0 min
[FeatSel] Result: Sepal.LengthPetal.Width (2 bits)
FeatSel result:
Features (2): Sepal.Length, Petal.Width
mmce.test.mean=0.0466667
```

Here, the last and the second result could be interesting because the features are different but the results are nearly the same. I only get the results but not the predictions/results on the different folds. 
Any idea how to extract them?

Answer (score 0):

You can get detailed information on what happened during the feature selection with the opt path:

```
cbind(getOptPathX(sfeats$opt.path), getOptPathY(sfeats$opt.path))

  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1            1           1            0           1
2            0           1            0           1
3            1           0            1           0
4            1           0            0           0
5            0           0            0           0
  getOptPathY(sfeats$opt.path)
1                   0.05333333
2                   0.06666667
3                   0.06000000
4                   0.28000000
5                   0.63333333
```

The individual predictions are not saved, however.

I don't really understand where you're going with this though (and mlr doesn't fuse a learner with a random subset of features). The way you apply feature selection is specific to a particular learner, and the result you get is not really transferable to another one. If you want to combine multiple learners in an ensemble with feature selection, just wrap each individual one with feature selection and put them in the ensemble. This way you'll get the best features for each learner.